# Has it every happened that a team that was ranked in the top 5 anytime during the season didn't make the NCAA Tournament?

Tags: basketball, history, collegiate

Has it ever happened that a team that was ranked in the top 5 anytime during the season didn't make the NCAA Tournament?

Answer (score 4):

> Has it ever happened that a team that was ranked in the top 5 anytime during the season didn't make the NCAA Tournament?

Yes.

The [most recent instance](http://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/seasons/2013-polls.html) took place during the 2012-2013 season. Kentucky was ranked #3 in the preseason AP and Coaches' polls and held that ranking in both polls up to week 2. By week 5 (with the exception of week 15), Kentucky was outside the top 25 in the AP poll. By week 9, Kentucky was outside the top 25 in the Coaches' poll.

[This](http://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/seasons/2016-polls.html) page from Sports Reference shows the top 25 teams in the AP and Coaches' poll for each week during a season and * indicates a NCAA tournament team. Parsing through these per season may yield more results.